# Struts 2 Message Store Interceptor Removing Errors on No Redirect

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am having an issue with the Message Store Interceptor in Struts 2. I have the following action in my struts.xml file:

```
<action name="rfi" method="add" class="org.test.action.RfiAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result name="error">../display/irrt/rfi.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">../display/irrt/rfi.jsp</result>
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">rfis</param>
        <param name="namespace">/irrt</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

When the action returns successfully, it redirects to the action listed and the success message is properly saved and retrieved by the interceptor.

However, when an error occurs, there is no redirect and it goes to the listed JSP page but the error doesn't show up (all other data does). It's like the MessageStoreInterceptor wipes out the contents of the error variables when it runs so that if no redirect occurs, the current action no longer has the error message.

This happens when the interceptor is set to either STORE or AUTOMATIC mode (even though the interceptor shouldn't even run if it's in AUTOMATIC mode and the result doesn't include a redirect).

My code only ever adds errors or messages. It never deletes them. The action code is below:

```
private String add()
{
    try
    {
        // add the rfi entry
        this.rfiService.addRfi(this.rfiEntry, this.getLoggedInUser());
    }
    catch(ConnectionException e)
    {
        this.addActionError("Could not add RFI entry.");
        e.printStackTrace();

        return ERROR;
    }

    // set success message
    this.addActionMessage("RFI entry added.");

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the code in the JSP being used to display the messages:

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors() == true">
    <s:iterator value="actionErrors">
        <p class="text"><b><font color="red"><s:property /></font></b></p>
    </s:iterator>
</s:if>
<s:elseif test="hasActionMessages() == true">
    <s:iterator value="actionMessages">
        <p class="text"><b><font color="green"><s:property /></font></b></p>
    </s:iterator>
</s:elseif>
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the include on this particular page that included the errors.

Moral of the story: don't assume code that's on every single other page is on the one that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">rfis</param>
        <param name="namespace">/irrt</param>
    </result>
```

The redirectAction `rfis` should also go through the `store` interceptor.

```
<action name="rfis" class="..." method="...">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result ..../>
</action>
```

Comment: The 'rfis' action does go through the interceptor. This is concerning the rfi action when it goes to either the the "error" or "input" result (the results where there is no redirection at all). When it goes through those results, the action errors aren't showing up.

Comment: you mean to say that using `s:actionerror` or `s:actionmessage` doesn't show the errors/messages ?

Comment: That's correct. I'm using an iterator above to iterate through the action errors or messages, however, I just tried with the s:actionerror and s:actionmessage tags and it still doesn't show up.